# Macro variable is not printing the table value but instead the column name

Tags: sql, sas, enterprise-guide

I want to assign these table values to macro variables:

[image: Table values]

This is how I assign the table value to the macro variable:

```
PROC SQL;
   CREATE TABLE Format_YYYYMM_tbl AS 
   SELECT t1.str_perdag_SAS_default FORMAT=YYMMN6. AS Format_YYYYMM,
          ("'"!!put(t1.str_perdag_SAS_default, YYMMN6.)!!"'") AS Format_YYYYMM_quo
      FROM DATOSTAMP t1;
QUIT;

PROC SQL NOPRINT;
SELECT DISTINCT 
          Format_YYYYMM,
          Format_YYYYMM_quo
          
INTO      :Format_YYYYMM,
          :Format_YYYYMM_quo
 
FROM Format_YYYYMM_tbl;

QUIT;
```

The issue is when I print the values in the log i get the following and not the value in the table:

```
49         %put Format_YYYYMM_quo;
Format_YYYYMM_quo
50         %put Format_YYYYMM;
Format_YYYYMM
```

What am I doing wrong?
I hope you can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your %PUT statement is NOT trying to show the value of the macro variables.  To reference the value of a macro variable use `&` before the name of the macro variable.

```
%put &Format_YYYYMM_quo;
```

In the %PUT statement only you can use a special syntax that will print both the name and the value separated by an =.

```
%put &=Format_YYYYMM &=Format_YYYYMM_quo;
```

Comment: Thank you @Tom, for your answer but could you elaborate the last paragraf I am not quite sure what you mean:
"In the %PUT statement only you can use a special syntax that will print both the name and the value separated by an =.

%put &=Format_YYYYMM &=Format_YYYYMM_quo;"

Comment: You can evaluate a macro variable to generate code any where.  So the first %PUT statement is just an example of evaluating a macro variable.  But the %PUT statement also allows you to use the &= prefix that you cannot use anywhere else.  Try running the %PUT statement both ways and see the difference it what i writes.